# DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch not returning an exact DateTime object

Tags: dart

I'm trying to construct a DateTime object from an int I get from a database, but the returned object is not equal to the original one, here's some test code:

```
void main() {
  final d = DateTime.now();
  final ms = d.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  final d1 = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ms).;
  print(d);
  print(d1);
  print(d1 == d);
}
```

which outputs (Running as a console app in android studio):

```
2020-03-18 20:57:14.887582
2020-03-18 20:57:14.887
false
```

However, running this code in a [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/4cf05e89401745159f36081f122efd57) outputs that the two objects are equal.
What am I missing?

Comment: Well.. seems to make sense that the precision you get from a `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()` call is indeed milliseconds, and the fact that `.Now()` happens to offer better precision makes it expected that those values could not be equal.

Comment: I'm not sure about DartPad, but I'm guessing the resolution of the internal clock on the machine it's executing on is only milliseconds, allowing the values to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, running this code in a DartPad outputs that the two objects are equal. What am I missing?

When you run the Dart code on the web, including DartPad, note that printing the result of `DateTime.now()` does *not* print a time with microsecond precision.  Your question therefore actually is *not* about the equality check (both objects do represent the same time and should be equal), it's why `DateTime` is not as precise in DartPad as on other platforms.

Modern web browsers have explicitly *reduced* timer precision in an effort to thwart timing-based attacks (e.g. Spectre).  See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#reduced_time_precision
- https://v8.dev/blog/spectre#high-precision-timers.

Additionally, Dart for the web is transpiled to JavaScript and also is subject to limitations of JavaScript.  [JavaScript `Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) simply don't support microseconds, so Dart `DateTime` objects also won't report microseconds in that environment. (Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44876.)