# How can i increase only 1 microsecond to DateTime.now() in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, duration

i have the following

```
Dateime.now() + here i need to increase only 1 microsecond
```

so  wanted output is `Dateime.now()` + that incensement which is   `1 microsecond`

i tried the following but it does not work

```
print(DateTime.now()+const Duration(microsecond : 1);)
```

How can i implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This well get it done.

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final later = now.add(const Duration(millisecond: 1));
```

check docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Or do it in a single line:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now().add(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
print(now);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. [`DateTime`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) does not define an `operator +`, but it does have an [`add` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) that accepts a `Duration`. (You also have a couple of syntax errors in your code; the semicolon is misplaced, and the named parameter to `Duration` is `microseconds`, not `microsecond`.)
2. If you're testing with Dart for the Web (such as with DartPad), you will *not* get microsecond precision due to limitations with JavaScript.  Running the following code in the Dart *VM* will show a change in microseconds:

   ```dart
   void main() {
     var now = DateTime.now();
     const microsecond = Duration(microseconds: 1);
     print(now);                  // Prints: 2022-04-23 20:39:28.295803
     print(now.add(microsecond)); // Prints: 2022-04-23 20:39:28.295804
   }
   ```

   Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60747710/